# Solve the equation $\sqrt{3x+2}+\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{3x+2}}=2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Solve the equation $$\sqrt{3x+2}+\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{3x+2}}=2x$$
We have $DM:3x+2>0,x>-\dfrac23, x\in DM=\left(-\dfrac23;+\infty\right)$, so we can multiply the whole equation by $\sqrt{3x+2}\ne0$. Then we will have $$3x+2+x^2=2x\sqrt{3x+2}\\x^2+3x+2-2x\sqrt{3x+2}=0\\(x+1)(x+2)-2x\sqrt{3x+2}=0$$ What next? Thank you!

Comment: Suggestion: Let $3x+2=u^2$, and rewrite the equation as a polynomial in $u$.

Comment: Square both sides of equation (of line 1) to get rid of the square root, it may bring spurious solutions, so plug them in initial equation to verify they work.

Answer (score 6):

Rewrite the equation as $$\left(\sqrt[4]{3x + 2} - \frac x{\sqrt[4]{3x+2}}\right)^2 = 0.$$ It follows that $\sqrt{3x+2} = x$ and then $x^2 - 3x - 2 = 0$. Note that we require $x \geq 0$.

Comment: Such an elegant answer!

Answer (score 3):

There is a clever solution here: it requires using AM-GM.

Assume that $\sqrt{3x+2} \geq 0$, which clearly must be true. Then, By AM-GM, we have
$$
\sqrt{3x+2} + \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{3x+2}} \geq 2\sqrt{x^2} = 2x
$$
with equality if and only if $\sqrt{3x+2} = \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{3x+2}}$. This is true when $x^2 = 3x+2$, or $x = \frac{3 \pm \sqrt{17}}{2}$. Clearly, we must have $x \geq \frac{-2}{3}$, so the only real solution is $\frac{3 + \sqrt{17}}{2}$.

Comment: +1 Dammit! Just beat me. Though you should mention why $\sqrt{x^2} = x$, i.e. why $x \ge 0$.

Comment: I think I solved it too honestly. +1.

Comment: *A priori* you don't know $x \geq 0$ so the step $2\sqrt{x^2} = 2x$ is not justified. It is however easy to see $x \geq 0$.

Comment: Note that $\frac{3-\sqrt{17}}2\ge -\frac 23$ so your argument to exclude it this way does not truly work.

Comment: @WhatsUp It's not too hard to justify. Just note that, if $x$ satisfies the original equation, then $2x$ is the sum of two non-negative numbers.

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes, or simply use $2\sqrt{x^2} = 2|x| \geq 2x$.

Answer (score 3):

Multiply by $\sqrt{3x+2}$, assuming $3x+2\ge 0$ i.e. $x\ge-2/3$:

$$\left(\sqrt{3x+2}\right)^2-2x\sqrt{3x+2}+x^2=0$$
$$\left(\sqrt{3x+2}-x\right)^2=0$$
$$\sqrt{3x+2}=x$$
$$3x+2=x^2$$

Solve the quadratic equation to find $x=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{17}}{2}$. As the final equation is a consequence of the original one, but not necessarily equivalent to it, you now need to try those two solutions in the original equation. The only real solution will turn out to be $x=\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{2}$ : the other one will be spurious and needs to be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

First multiply by $\sqrt{3x+2}$ to get

$$3x+2 + x^2 = 2x \sqrt{3x+2}$$

Then square both sides

\begin{align*}
(x^2+3x+2)^2 &= 4x^2(3x+2)\\
x^4+6x^3+13x^2+12x+4 &= 12x^3+8x^2 \\
x^4-6x^3+5x^2+12x+4 &=0
\end{align*}

Try to solve this polynomial equation, giving you the true solution and one false solution that you have to exclude. It is helpful to observe that

$$x^4-6x^3+5x^2+12x+4 = x^4-2x^2(3x+2) + (3x+2)^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend this method. You already got $(x+1)(x+2)-2x\sqrt{3x+2}=0$. And by this, $x\ge0$ is induced right away, because the left hand is $>0$.

Then...

$$
(x+1)(x+2)=2x\sqrt{3x+2}\\
(x+1)^2(x+2)^2=4x^2(3x+2)\\
x^4-6x^3+5x^2+12x+4=0
$$

This is sure a quatric, so seems hard to solve. But...

> Let $x^2-3x=y$, then this quatric changes $y^2-4y+4=0$.
> So $y=2$, $x^2-3x-2=0$.
> Then we get two roots, $x=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{17}}2$. $\frac{3-\sqrt{17}}2$ is out of range.
> So the answer is ${x=\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}2}$.